# ask underlying papers of MEAN SHIFT, OPTICAL FLOW, KALMAN FILTER

Tags: computer-vision

I need 3 **underlying papers** / most top tree in regard to MEAN SHIFT, OPTICAL FLOW, KALMAN FILTER.
I've searched in ieee xplore, it showed many related papers.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @de wit: Nope, I just confused how to seek top papers in spesific title. If you have any suggestion in regards to how to find first/popular paper in spesific method, please let me know. As far as I know, I just can find it in related paper and they definitely refer to previous papers. Any other idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know about [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/)?

For Mean Shift I get [Mean shift: A robust approach toward feature space analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.160.3832&rank=1), which is a very good paper on that topic.

For the other topics I cannot help you, but you generally find good papers by reading papers and looking at the references.

Answer (score 2):

These are old unsolved yet classic Computer Vision problems:

- **Mean Shift**
  [Mean shift: A robust approach toward feature space analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.160.3832&rank=1) [same as bjoernz] but in practice, I would prefer a completely different unsupervised segmentation work from Felzenszwalb *et al.* [Efficient graph-based segmentation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~pff/segment/) (faster + better)
- **Optical Flow**

  - **Sparse** reliable points: [Good Features to track](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jshi/papers/good-features.ps.gz) is a nice summary of what is called the KLT literature (for Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi ... poor Jianbo Shi). In a nutshell, some points (corners) in your images are easier to track than others in uniform regions for example.
  - **Dense** for each pixel: [Horn-Schunk historical paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/papers/Optical_Flow_OPT.pdf) but check out recent Thomas Brox and Jitendra Malik works and also the one Ce Liu also publish.
- **Kalman filter**: [Historical Paper](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/kalman/kalmanPaper.html) but I do not think it is still cited a lot because everybody seems to refer to their favorite textbooks instead.

For efficient implementations of almost all these nice articles: OpenCV at the rescue!

***Caveat***: Machine Learning people who are very trendy in Computer Vision these days are sometimes confused by the word *features*. Indeed, one can distinguish:

- Detectors: that selects sparse points in the image ( corners like e.g. Hessian, Harris ...)
- Descriptors: that describe these points and also the image through concatenation
- Features space: a fancy way to describe their kernel-SVM stuff for recognition

For example, SIFT is both a detector and a descriptor technique although it is called *a feature*.